# Asp dot net RangeValidator Error in Code Behind file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a Range Validator in aspx file. But I am not able to access this RangeValidator in code behind file (aspx.cs)

```
<asp:RangeValidator id="valDateRange" runat="server"  ControlToValidate="txtValDate" Type="Date" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage= "*"/>
```

Code Behind: (I need to use following code in the code behind file in Page_Load method.)

```
valDateRange.MinimumValue = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
valDateRange.MaximumValue = DateTime.Today.AddDays(180).ToShortDateString();
```

> Error: Cannot resolve symbol valDateRange.

Comment: Did you try to configure your environment to enable annotation processing (which should generate the missing classes)